# Retrieve wiki pages or web part pages from a document Using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I want to retrieve all wiki pages and web part pages from a document library using CSOM.

I am able to retrieve only publishing pages in following way.

```
PublishingPage page = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(customContext.Context, item);
```

Here `item` is a page from library. Is there any way that i can retrieve wiki pages or webpart pages in same way?